# Get values of filtered keys

Tags: javascript

This returns just the keys.  But how do I get an array back of entire objects back based on if the keys have the text "country" in them?

So far this returns the right keys but only the keys.  I need the **objects** returned back for the filter not just keys.

`communitySections = Object.keys(stateValues).filter(key => { return key.includes('country')})`

I'm trying to filter out certain objects, the that have `country` in its key names.

[image]

Comment: `communitySections = stateValues.filter(v => v.country);`

Comment: no that doesn't limit it where the keys contain the word "country" in the key's name

Comment: Sorry, I thought it is an array.  You can: `const communitySections = {}; for(let k in stateValues) {if(k.includes('country')) {communitySections[k] = stateValues[k]}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
var obj = { 
  a_en: {foo : 1, bar: 1},
  b_en: {foo : 1, bar: 2},
  c_fr: {foo : 2, bar: 3},
}

var filtered = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([k, o]) => k.includes('en')));
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
communitySections = Object.keys(stateValues).reduce(output, key => {
    return key.includes('country') ? output[key] = stateValues[key] : '', output;
}, {});
```